# "TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined" in react js?

Tags: reactjs

**I'm currently working on form validation in react but in output it says "TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined"** Can someone please help me where I'm going wrong?

```
handleUserInput(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ [name]: value },
    () =>{this.validateField(name,value)});
    
  }
 
validateField(fieldName,value){
  let fieldValidationErrors=this.state.formErrors;
  let emailValid = this.state.emailValid;
  let passwordValid = this.state.passwordValid;
 
  switch(fieldName){
    case 'email':
      emailValid = value.match(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.);+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
      fieldValidationErrors.email= emailValid?'':'invalid';
      break;
 
    case 'password':
      passwordValid=value.match(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{10,}$/);
      fieldValidationErrors.password=passwordValid?'':'invalid';
     break;
     default:
     break; 
  }
    this.setState({emailValid: emailValid,
      passwordValid: passwordValid},this.validateForm);
}
```

Comment: fieldValidationErrors is null or undefined. That's the issue ai think

Comment: what is the initialValue for this.state.formErrors  ?

Comment: Can you post your state?

Comment: formErrors : {email: ' ', password: ' ' }

Comment: If you are up for a refactor you can try destructuring your state as `let { emailValid, passwordValid, formErrors: fieldValidationErrors } = this.state` . You can do the same for `const { name , value } = e.target` .